# InvalidOperationException when trying to edit a DataGrid cell

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, invalidoperationexception

My purpose is to be able to bind to WPF controls classes that are obtained from some notification mechanism.

I have defined an MyList class that holds MyItem objects. These MyItem objects have runtime defined properties. So, MyItem implements ICustomTypeDescriptor.
I want the controls to be notified when values change, so it also implements INotifyPropertyChanged. And because I had problem with edition, I also made it implement IEditableObject.

So, I have the MyItem class defined as:

```
public class MyItem: BaseClass, INotifyPropertyChanged, ICustomTypeDescriptor, IEditable {
//...
}
```

where BaseClass is my original class I want to make visible to WPF controls.

MyList, on its side, implements IEnumerable as this is what is expected for DataGrid.ItemsSource, INotifyCollectionChanged because I want the control to be notified for new rows, IEditableCollectionView and IList to try to solve my edition problem.

So, I have the following class definition:

```
public class MyList : BaseClass, INotifyCollectionChanged, IEnumerable<MyItem>,
                      IEditableCollectionView, IList<MyItem>
{
  private List<MyItem> _list = new List<MyItem(); // holds items
//...
}
```

When I set this list as items source to a data grid, everything seems to work fine: The column of the data grid are the declared dynamic properties through the ICustomTypeDescriptor interface. The value of each cell is correctly displayed.

But I soon as I double click on a cell for editing it, I get an InvalidOperationException without any stack trace or more explicit message.

I have no idea on what I should do to make it work. I have tried all the possible solutions I have found here or elsewhere on the web.

Has anyone an idea on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the non-generic `IList` interface in your `MyList` class and also make sure that you don't add any items directly to the `Items` collection of the `DataGrid` control: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9deaa308-37e8-4110-814f-30d2de7c2654/datagrid-edititem-is-not-allowed-for-this-view?forum=wpf

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not work.
I've just tried and, as an effect, the ICustomTypeDescriptor is no longer taken into account.
It means that the datagrid displays real properties of my BaseClass instead of showing the dynamic properties I need to show.

Comment: I don't think this is supported then.